# How can I remove a last part of a string with an unknown int?

Tags: c#, string

So, I'm making a file transfer program from one PC in my house to the other. The client can look through the server's files and take what it wants. (Makes it very easy for moving projects/documents/music). This is an example of what a string of a file looks like:

```
New Text Document.txt : "(FILE)-(" + f.Length + " Bytes)"
```

My problem is removing  : "(FILE)-(" + f.Length + " Bytes)".
How can I remove JUST that part from the string? Where the f.Length is unknown...
Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using regexes?

Comment: string[] strs = str.Split(':);
strs[1] is the part u want removed. is it correct?

Comment: +1 to regexps. If you have some random  (not known at coding time) part of string before the int, it would be the most appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've got what you want

```
string contents = "some text (FILE)-(5435 Bytes)  another text";

string result = Regex.Replace(contents, @"\(FILE\)-\(\d+ Bytes\)", "");

Console.WriteLine (result);
```

Prints:

```
some text   another text
```

Solution to remove everything after `.txt`

```
string contents = "some text .txt (FILE)-(5435 Bytes)  another text";
string lastSegment = ".txt";
var result = contents.Substring(0, contents.IndexOf(lastSegment) + lastSegment.Length);
Console.WriteLine (result);
```

prints `some text .txt`

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it, but does that remove the : as well as the rest of the end?

Comment: Do you want to remove **all** file contents followed after `Bytes)`?

Comment: New Text Document.txt : "(FILE)-(" + f.Length + " Bytes)"
I want to remove EVERYTHING after the .txt - but the f.Length will be an unknown int in runtime...

Comment: so remove everything after `.txt` with contents. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to the regex answers, one option is to use LastIndexOf to find the last occurence of a known part of the string (e.g. `(FILE)`).

```
var oldString = "ThisIsAString (FILE)-(1234 Bytes";
int indexToRemoveTo = oldString.LastIndexOf("(FILE)");

// Get all the characters from the start of the string to "(FILE)"
var newString = oldString.Substring(0, indexToRemoveTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Match(pattern: @"\((.*)\)-\(\d+ Bytes\)$", input: name);
if(match.Success)
{
    string fileName = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: "\(" is not a valid escape character.